# Deleted table in database. How do I get entity framework to remake it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wrongly assumed that if I deleted a table in the database then EF would re-create an empty table next time I ran update-database.

Now I have a missing table so the application throws an exception any time it hits a reference to it.

Is there a way to tell EF to remake the table without completely deleting the database?

Comment: couldn't you just recreate the table using a `create table` command?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible, but for the next time if you want to clean a table and make it look like a new one without dropping it, I would recommend you to use the `truncate table` command

Answer (score 3):

The issue is EF has the table in it's snapshot with the last migration, so if you want EF to recreate it you could do this:

1) Temporarily remove the class by commenting out the DbSet and OnModelCreating (if exists).

2) Run a migration so EF removes the table from the snapshot. You will need to comment out the code in the Up() method that removes the table since it's already deleted.

3) Uncomment step 1 code.

4) Run another migration to add the table back.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn481501?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: trying this gets me `Cannot drop the table 'dbo.TableName', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

Comment: don't forget to uncommend all DBSets that have a relationship with the Table that you want to restore. As you mentioned, people should also remember to comment out the fluent-Api calls in the "OnModelCreating" function to get it to write "DropTable" in the migration file (which we then have to delete as you already wrote of course)

Comment: I doubt this will work because that DbSet is referenced in your code and to add a migration your program has to build and it will throw errors trying to build because you removed that DbSet from DBContext, see my solution below

Answer (score 1):

Just comment the table property  from  `DbContext` And Update.After That `Un Comment`  the property and Update This will  create a new table without  deleting the entire database (This works for me While updating through package manager console)

Comment: i think the issue is table has a many to many relationship with my main data table as its not letting me do that

Answer (score 0):

1) Create the database locally in your computer from scratch

2) with SSM open the database and select the desired table

3) right mouse click on the table and select "script Table as" and then "Create To" --> this will generate the table creation as Sql string

4) Excute the generate query with in the application ExecuteSqlCommand

Example from my PC:

```
string toBeCreatetable = @"  
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers]( 
    [CustomerId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
( 
    [CustomerId] ASC 
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]"; 

// Somewhere in code before at the begin do:    
using (var ctx = new myDbContext(toBeCreatetable))
{
    int executed= myDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()
}
```

This is the best way which guarantee that the migration history will be properly working with the conceptual model.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your migration snapshot comment out the code that pertains to the particular table you deleted.
2. add-migration Fixit
3. update-database
4. The table will be recreated
5. If you are using a DBintializer routine in your code then have it check for any data existing in the table - if not then repopulate your table

   ```
    if (!context.MyDBSet.Any())
    {
        var myData = new TableData[]
            {
    new TableData{ Data = null },
    new TableData{ Data = "Yes" },
    new TableData{ Data = "No" },
            };

        foreach (TableData d in myData)
        {
            context.MyDBSet.Add(d);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your SSOX, if you find your `Tables` folder, you will find the one called `__MigrationHistory`. Delete that one and run `Update-Database`. This should recreate the table according to the schema that you have.